# Using a FrontEndToken in an init.m file

Tags: front-end

I'm trying to create Menu Command that selects all cells in a notebook and closes them.  I am able to select all the cells but cannot close them.  Below is my attempt I placed in an init.m file.

```
FrontEndExecute[
  FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
   "DuplicatePreviousOutput",
   {MenuItem[
     "Close All Groups", {FrontEnd`KernelExecute[
       SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Notebook]];
      FrontEnd`KernelExecute[
       FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "SelectionCloseAllGroups"]]},
     FrontEnd`MenuKey["c", FrontEnd`Modifiers -> {"Control"}],
     System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
    ]}
  ]
];
```

I believe my problem is using the `FrontEndToken` in the init.m file.  I'm not sure how to use them in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead...

```
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["DuplicatePreviousOutput",
  {
   MenuItem["Close All Groups",
    FrontEnd`KernelExecute[
      SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Notebook];
      FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[],"SelectionCloseAllGroups"]
    ], 
    FrontEnd`MenuKey["c", FrontEnd`Modifiers -> {"Control", "Shift"}],
    System`MenuEvaluator ->Automatic]
  }
]
```

I've moved the keyboard accelerator to Control + Shift, mainly for the benefit of Windows and Linux users.

Comment: This worked.  This should help me in the future with frontenstokens in unit.m files.  I get lost sometimes with namespaces.